# Looking for a child element within ElementHandle with waitFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, automated-tests, puppeteer

I have a specific listing that contains the lazy-loading calendar for each record. I catch them by

```
 docsPanels = await page. $$ ('[data-id = "result-item"]');
```

then I need to go to every element and check if the calendar actually loads for it. I need to check the calendar within the element I have from the list. Something like:

```
for (const panel of Object.values ​​(docsPanels)) {
            await panel.hover ({delay: 100});               // scroll to the record
            panel.waitForSelector ('.lazy-calendar-slot'); // checks the calendar within the element
        };
```

I wonder if there is anything like this, cause the `ElementHandle.$ ('selector')` which is the closest to my solution is working immediately. Any workaround, solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you need not `Object.values​​()` for the `docsPanels`: it is an array and you can iterate over it as is.
2. You can try [`page.waitForFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) with ElementHandle argument:

```js
for (const panel of docsPanels) {
  await panel.hover({delay: 100});
  await panel.waitForFunction(
    parent => parent.querySelector('.lazy-calendar-slot'),
    panel,
  );
};
```